# Can the cloth simulation be made to conserve momentum and guarantee equal and opposite reactions?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

The "Collision" and "Cloth" settings have to be enabled separately from each other for cloths that interact with each other.

This makes it seem like they will also be evaluated separately, such that a kind of race condition could occur where conservation of momentum is broken because the "collision" effect of one cloth on the other prevents the latter cloth from getting close enough to exert an equal and opposite reaction on the first cloth.

---

A quick test seems to confirm that that is indeed what happens:

[image]

With equal margins, the identical cloths exert mostly equivalent forces on each other, so Newton's Third Law of Motion is obeyed and their velocities cancel out on collision.

[image]

But when one cloth (left) has a significantly greater collision margin than the other one, then it behaves as if it has infinite momentum even though they should have the same mass, thus breaking Conservation of Momentum and Newton's Third. (It eventually stops because it enters the effector field for launching the other cloth, not because of collision.)

---

Is there any way to guarantee that colliding cloths will always experience equal and opposite forces?